# how can you create a login screen like the iPhone facebook app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, user-interface

The Facebook app for the iPhone has a great username/password setup where it almost looks like it is a uitableview with UITextField's inside the two rows, is this how it is done? Or would it be something different to this altogether?

If it is a tableview, how can I access the textfields inside the tableview once the user hits the Login button? Is there a quick way to iterate over the cells in a tableview?

A simple one, I know, but I didnt want to implement an elaborate tableview if I didnt need to...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The source**: https://github.com/c99koder/lastfm-iphone

Edited: It's possible you customize the UITableViewCell and put a UITextField inside. However, there is an even easy way to achieve this, since the login / signup page would almost always be static. See below.

LastFM for iPhone used a similar login / signup page design. And they open-sourced their code. Take a look at the nib file and you will know how LastFM did this. :-)

- Screenshot 1: original
- Screenshot 2: after I removed some of the background png files.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This solution feels a bit hackish to me when you can easily create a custom tableviewcell and use the UITextField delegate methods to interact with the values.

Comment: Can you please add a link to source?

Comment: 1) It's one of the solutions. 2) It requires less code with the same appearance and function. 3) We didn't hear any LastFM users dislike this app just because they realized the login / signup page was not made of authentic UITableViews.

Comment: @Black Frog: I just added the source link in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create a tableview controller and go to the xib file -> attributes inspector->tableview and select "group styled" instead of plain. Then u can customize the tableview cells in the code by adding the textfields for username and password. Then create a new UIView and set the view to the tableview's footer view for the login button.

For more explanation regarding the same, go through the answer for this question.

[Table view in iPhone in grouped style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413516/table-view-in-iphone-in-grouped-style/15521543#15521543)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's not using a `UITableView` at all (otherwise, you'd be able to scroll the page up and down). It's just two `UITextField`s over custom backgrounds (or with custom backgrounds).

Now, if you wanted to use a `UITableView`, what you could do is store as variables the `UITextField`s within the `UITableViewCell`s. Then, when the person clicks a login button, you just get the `text` value from the `UITextField`s.

But, again, if you wanted to emulate the Facebook look, you don't need to bother with the `UITableView`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, now that I understand your question (thanks @Jonathan!), yes it does look like it is a tableview using custom UITableViewCells with a UITextField.

After creating the custom cell with a UITextField you can assign your view controller as the UITextField delegate and access the values at various points through the delegate methods:

```
– textFieldShouldBeginEditing:
– textFieldDidBeginEditing:
– textFieldShouldEndEditing:
– textFieldDidEndEditing:
```

As an example, in your `textFieldShouldReturn:`, you can grab a reference to the indexPath of that cell with :

`NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.loginTable indexPathForCell:(MemberLoginCell*)[[textField superview] superview]];`

And then to the cell with:

`MemberLoginCell *cell = (MemberLoginCell*)[self.loginTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Or simply grab the `textField.text` value and assign it to an NSString that can be passed to your LOGIN method as required.

Comment: Actually you don't even need to do all of that, simply visit http://touch.facebook.com

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the native facebook app (http://www.trickyways.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/login-facebook-on-iphone.png)

Comment: @Jonathan heh you're probably right, I'll edit my answer accordingly!

Comment: Unfortunately the question is about the native app on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I know there's already an accepted answer, but I created a facebook-type login page, using a UITableView. The code is [here](https://github.com/Jon889/JPGeneral/tree/master/JPLoginTable) on github

Comment: there is nothing in that link related to login table.

Comment: how on earth? It was definitely in there previously, I'll take a look.

Comment: sure, there is simple empty subclass of UITableViewController. :)

Comment: Just found it, its uploading now :)