# Table view in iPhone in grouped style

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to populate data from database in to a table view in grouped style.
         No. of records can be varied.(Dynamically change)

I tried it, but I am  just able to create different sections in table view with heading .

for EX: my database has 5 field NAME,ADDRESS,CONTACT,SALARY,TECHNOLOGY.

So I want to put the name field value in header of section which I did.....successfully
but when I am trying to populate the other four fields values under the section then it will populate only for 1 section only.

Second problem is that when I scroll up and down the screen then values becomes misplaced means randomly changes their place.

Comment: I think you will soon get a comment, asking you to see some code. And especially the one you use to populate the table.

Comment: Please share your code with us. Especially your cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: i added the code....plz modify rowforindex portion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection done right.  Also the cellForRowAtIndexPath needs to be coded to identify the sections and the row within each section.  If you need a complete example, please post the code you are using now for that TableView and I can modify it to do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

First import the table view delegates in your .h file and make sure that you follow this format,

```
@interface CustomtableViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    UITextField * username;
    UIButton * submit;
}

@implementation CustomtableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, 300, 45)];
    submit = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [submit setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[submit setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.56] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [submit setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [submit.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
    [submit setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 15.0, 280.0, 44.0)];
    [newView addSubview:submit];

    [self.tableView setTableFooterView:newView];

   [super viewDidLoad];

}

  #pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        //self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake( 10,  320);
        [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50,0,0,0)];
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
        username = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
        username.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        username.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
            username.placeholder = @"example@gmail.com";
            username.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
            username.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Username";
            username.clearButtonMode = YES;
        }
        else {
            username.placeholder = @"minimum 6 characters";
            username.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            username.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            username.secureTextEntry = YES;
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Password";
            username.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
        }
        username.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        username.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // no auto correction support
        username.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; // no auto capitalization support
        username.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        username.tag = 0;


        username.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways; // no clear 'x' button to the right
        [username setEnabled: YES];


    [cell.contentView addSubview: username];

         }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Here, i've created just two textfields for username and password. You can use the else if condition to insert any no of textfields in each of the successive rows according to your needs.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"User Login"];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 50;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return @"";

}
```

So, my code here is just used for creating a login page with two textfields(Username and Password) and a Login button. You can modify my code according to your needs. 
Cheers!